# How to stream video from camcoder Sony HDR CX300 to a computer?

Tags: linux, windows, video-streaming, camcorder

Sony camcoder HDR CX300 is able to stream video to an Android phone over WIFI via [PlayMemories mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.playmemories.mobile). How to stream video from that camcoder over WIFI to a computer with Windows or Linux?

(Not by running the Android emulator on the computer:)

Comment: Because the streaming is probably a SONY thing you'll probably be limited with what you can do without PlayMemories installed on your other devices... Can you get a Windows version of PlayMemories?

Comment: @BigChris I have installed PlayMemories on Windows but it does not have the streaming functionality.